# Cannot deploy a MEAN stack app on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, mean

I want to develop a MEAN stack app on Heroku, however, it failed and throw me some errors and ask me to check the log. My application works fine on localhost, here is the app github link: https://github.com/zichenma/blackboard I have no idea what happen. Anyone can help me with this? Thank you so much in advanced!

```
2016-10-26T19:25:04.437140+00:00 app[web.1]: #   Unstable releases are available for preview/testing only.
2016-10-26T19:25:04.437211+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2016-10-26T19:25:04.437255+00:00 app[web.1]: ##############################################################
2016-10-26T19:25:04.437283+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-26T19:25:04.489004+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 19:25:04 GMT express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option at server.js:33:9
2016-10-26T19:25:04.490059+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 19:25:04 GMT express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at server.js:33:9
2016-10-26T19:25:04.490153+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2016-10-26T19:25:04.490155+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2016-10-26T19:25:04.490156+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2016-10-26T19:25:04.588917+00:00 app[web.1]: { [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
2016-10-26T19:26:02.387104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-10-26T19:26:02.387104+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-10-26T19:26:02.512694+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-10-26T19:26:02.584450+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-26T19:26:02.585639+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-26T19:26:04.361960+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2016-10-26T19:26:07.234279+00:00 app[web.1]: { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
2016-10-26T19:26:07.235703+00:00 app[web.1]: js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434343+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434389+00:00 app[web.1]: ##############################################################
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434444+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434485+00:00 app[web.1]: #   !!! MONGOOSE WARNING !!!
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434524+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434564+00:00 app[web.1]: #   This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose.
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434643+00:00 app[web.1]: #   DO NOT run this in production.
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434602+00:00 app[web.1]: #   Unstable releases are available for preview/testing only.
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434688+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434729+00:00 app[web.1]: ##############################################################
2016-10-26T19:26:07.434769+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-26T19:26:07.531910+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 19:26:07 GMT express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option at server.js:33:9
2016-10-26T19:26:07.533899+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 19:26:07 GMT express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at server.js:33:9
2016-10-26T19:26:07.630763+00:00 app[web.1]: { [MongoError: auth failed] name: 'MongoError', ok: 0, errmsg: 'auth failed', code: 18 }
2016-10-26T19:26:07.538978+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2016-10-26T19:26:07.538983+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2016-10-26T19:26:07.538984+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2016-10-26T19:26:24.587674+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=a2d7df9b-7e2f-467d-8d56-0952a7445c19 fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:27:04.738904+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-10-26T19:27:04.739029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-10-26T19:27:04.940692+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-10-26T19:27:04.973605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-26T19:27:06.449518+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=9855f356-0e8c-4263-81fc-772b1072cc45 fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:27:06.620739+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=cb5da5c7-15c1-4d81-9a7b-ab9aaf6c05d4 fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:27:07.049617+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=f19e3ed2-a72c-48f3-a42b-734d86d7ce67 fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:27:24.589248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=af99564e-dce2-4676-9969-124862c9f36b fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:27:24.969275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=6a853ff5-831d-4069-8f60-a1570f15795b fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:27:42.412204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=b7a68539-d9b5-485f-8c47-81d78995be2f fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:27:42.781982+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=621881ff-990b-425f-b31a-e7a990ddbbe5 fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:32:24.969477+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=5429d788-e362-4769-8d10-f830856ca24a fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:32:25.256442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=bbd4c7b8-a8e3-461e-8630-8cd2da7cd58f fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:37:35.811641+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e841e2b by mazichen1984@gmail.com
2016-10-26T19:37:35.811736+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by mazichen1984@gmail.com
2016-10-26T19:37:36.054933+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-26T19:37:36.054944+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-26T19:37:36.492951+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-26T19:37:37.808413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2016-10-26T19:37:39.901939+00:00 app[web.1]: js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
2016-10-26T19:37:39.900937+00:00 app[web.1]: { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050266+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050286+00:00 app[web.1]: ##############################################################
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050325+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050354+00:00 app[web.1]: #   !!! MONGOOSE WARNING !!!
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050392+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050418+00:00 app[web.1]: #   This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose.
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050447+00:00 app[web.1]: #   DO NOT run this in production.
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050445+00:00 app[web.1]: #   Unstable releases are available for preview/testing only.
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050466+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050515+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-26T19:37:40.050493+00:00 app[web.1]: ##############################################################
2016-10-26T19:37:40.094020+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 19:37:40 GMT express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option at server.js:33:9
2016-10-26T19:37:40.094930+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 19:37:40 GMT express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at server.js:33:9
2016-10-26T19:37:40.095011+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2016-10-26T19:37:40.095012+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2016-10-26T19:37:40.095012+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2016-10-26T19:37:40.134038+00:00 app[web.1]: [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
2016-10-26T19:37:40.252494+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-26T19:37:40.253488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-26T19:37:40.234424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-10-26T19:37:41.790766+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2016-10-26T19:37:44.134867+00:00 app[web.1]: { [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
2016-10-26T19:37:44.135992+00:00 app[web.1]: js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
2016-10-26T19:37:44.501677+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-26T19:37:44.501724+00:00 app[web.1]: ##############################################################
2016-10-26T19:37:44.501769+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2016-10-26T19:37:44.501809+00:00 app[web.1]: #   !!! MONGOOSE WARNING !!!
2016-10-26T19:37:44.501846+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2016-10-26T19:37:44.501886+00:00 app[web.1]: #   This is an UNSTABLE release of Mongoose.
2016-10-26T19:37:44.501922+00:00 app[web.1]: #   Unstable releases are available for preview/testing only.
2016-10-26T19:37:44.501959+00:00 app[web.1]: #   DO NOT run this in production.
2016-10-26T19:37:44.502010+00:00 app[web.1]: #
2016-10-26T19:37:44.502042+00:00 app[web.1]: ##############################################################
2016-10-26T19:37:44.502060+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-10-26T19:37:44.608668+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 19:37:44 GMT express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option at server.js:33:9
2016-10-26T19:37:44.609658+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 26 Oct 2016 19:37:44 GMT express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at server.js:33:9
2016-10-26T19:37:44.609748+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2016-10-26T19:37:44.609745+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2016-10-26T19:37:44.638489+00:00 app[web.1]: [Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]]
2016-10-26T19:37:44.609747+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2016-10-26T19:37:44.730255+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-26T19:37:44.718868+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-10-26T19:37:48.073902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=e8562216-4639-4014-b497-0f976fe8d463 fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-26T19:37:48.424557+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zichenblackboard.herokuapp.com request_id=70192eaa-2e82-4037-a7a3-43d32e4c8c54 fwd="129.10.9.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

My server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
//initialize mongoose schemas
require('./models/models');
require('./models/course');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var authenticate = require('./routes/authenticate')(passport);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                         //add for Mongo support
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||'mongodb://localhost:27017/courseManager', function (err) {
    if(err){
        console.error(err)
    }else {
        console.log("connected");
    }
});              //connect to Mongo
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/',index);
app.use('/auth', authenticate);
app.use('/api', api);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

//// Initialize Passport
var initPassport = require('./passport-init');
initPassport(passport);

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: How do you start this application locally?

Comment: Hello @BradleyJohnson, you just need to clone from my github https://github.com/zichenma/blackboard.git and and then go to Command Window, input npm install and npm start. It will run on your local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your `Procfile` is instructing Heroku's orchestration to start the process with `node server.js`. Change that line in your `Procfile` to `web: npm start` or `web: bin/www`.

Comment: Thank you so so so much! I changed Procfile to web: bin/www, finally it worked! Appreciated your help!